# Why is gdb so slow in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, gdb, mingw

I recently noticed that running a program inside gdb in windows makes it a lot slower, and I want to know why.

Here's an example:

- It is a pure C++03 project, compiled with mingw32 (gcc 4.8.1, 32 bits).
- It is statically linked against libstdc++ and libgcc, no other lib is used.
- It is a cpu and memory intensive non-parallel process (a mesh edition operation, lots of news and deletes and queries to data structures involved).
- The problem is not start-up time, the whole process is painfully slow.
- **Debug build (-O0 -g2) runs in 8 secs outside gdb, but in 140 secs within gdb.**
- Tested from command line, just launching gdb and just typing "run" (no breakpoints defined).
- I also tested a release build (optimized, and without debugging information), and it is still much slower inside gdb (3 secs vs 140 secs; yes, it takes the same time as the not optimized version inside gdb).
- Tested with gdb 7.5 and 7.6 from mingw32 project, and with a gdb 7.8 compiled by me (all of them without python support).
- I usually develop on a GNU/Linux box, and there I can't notice speed differences between running with or withoud gdb.

I want to know what is gdb doing that is making it run so slowly. I have some basic understanding of how a debugger works, but I cannot figure out what is it doing here, and googling didn't helped me this time.

Comment: Some extra info: I've just profiled the app with gprof, with and without gdb and results are very similar, the extra time does not seems to be there. I've also compiled gdb with -pg, but haven't found anything strange so far.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried running this with a different windows debugger like ollydbg, VS integrated debugger, windbg etc.? How do their run-time performance compare to mingw-gdb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally found the problem, thanks to greatwolf for asking me to test other debuggers. Ollydbg takes the same time as gdb, so it's not a gdb problem, its a Windows problem. This tip changed my search criteria and then I've found this article* that explains the problem very well and gives a really simple solution: define an environment varible _NO_DEBUG_HEAP to 1. This will disable the use of a special heap system windows provides and c++ programs use.

* Here's the link: http://preshing.com/20110717/the-windows-heap-is-slow-when-launched-from-the-debugger/

Comment: This works under my MSYS2's 64bit GCC compiler + GDB, it make the debugging session very fast, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I once had issues with gdb being incredibly slow and I remember disabling nls (native language support, i.e. the translations of all the messages) would remedy this.

The configure time option is `--disable-nls`. I might have just been mistaken as to what is the true cause, but it's worth a shot for you anyways.

My bug report from back then is [here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14619), although the conclusion there would be that I was mistaken. If you can provide further insight into this, that would be great!

Comment: I compiled the latest gdb version (7.8.1) myself with and without that option, and there was no difference. I read about it before, but I think it was related to the loading of huge shared libraries (such as qt).

Comment: @Zaskar While the `Qt` part might be true I'm using it on both a Debian and Win10 system. On Debian things load much faster (including all the Debian-relevant libraries) while on Win10 it loads a ton of other Windows-related libraries which take probably 2/3 of the loading times during a debugging session.